# Showing that $\sup(A\cdot B) = \sup(A)\cdot\sup(B)$ for $A$ and $B$ subsets of non-negative reals

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

> While  $A \cdot B=\{x \cdot y \mid x \in A, y \in B\}$, show that, for $A$, $B \subseteq [0,\infty)$,
>   $$\sup(A \cdot B)= \sup(A) \cdot \sup(B)$$

My demonstration:

First:

$$\forall a\in A, a\le\sup(A)$$ 
$$\forall b\in B, b\le\sup(B)$$

so, 
$$\begin{align}
a\cdot b\le\sup(A)\cdot\sup(B)
&\implies  
a\cdot b \le \sup(A \cdot B)\le\sup(A)\cdot\sup(B) \\
&\implies 
\sup(A\cdot B)\le\sup(A)\cdot\sup(B) \tag{1}
\end{align}$$

Second: Using $(1)$, while $b\ne0$, 
$$a \le \frac{sup(A\cdot B)}{b} \implies \sup(A)\le \frac{\sup(A\cdot B)}{b}$$

so 
$$\begin{align}
b\le\frac{\sup(A\cdot B)}{\sup(A)} 
&\implies \sup(B)\le \frac{\sup(A\cdot B)}{\sup(A)} \\
&\implies \sup(A)\cdot\sup(B)\le \sup(A\cdot B) \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

Then $(1)$ and $(2)$ imply
$$\sup(A \cdot B)= \sup(A) \cdot \sup(B) \tag{3}$$

> Is the demonstration correct? Can the case $b = 0$ be discarded for being trivial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is basically correct. But you should have started your proof by saying that the cases in which $A=\{0\}$ or $B=\{0\}$ are trivial and that you will assume that $A,B\neq\{0\}$.

Comment: thanks!!I will be more rigorous next time.